# How to migrate mysql user data to keycloak

Tags: mysql, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

how can i migrate mysql user data to keycloak

I want to keycloak migrate mysql user data. After some research, I came across such a plugin.  `[https://github.com/daniel-frak/keycloak-user-migration](https://github.com/daniel-frak/keycloak-user-migration)`

I installed it as desired, ran it and gave the rest api url. (there is an example rest project in the repo, I tried it too) but as a result of my attempts, when I want to log in with the user information I call with get, it cannot find the data.

Where am I going wrong if anyone is using this plugin? Or how can I pass the user data in mysql here? is there a different method?